# Problems with Fast User Switching in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, login, microsoft-account, fast-user-switching

## Problems with Fast User Switching in Windows 10

### Problem description

I share a laptop with 3 other family members. All three of us have accounts on the laptop; mine is a local admin account but now sync'ed to my MS account. The other two are MS accounts added to the laptop via **Settings > Accounts > Family & other users > Add a family member**.

The "Switch User" icon/button is missing in Windows 10 from (at least) the following locations, regardless of which user is logged in:

- Lock/logon screen (no user profile icons shown)
- Start Menu (click on my user icon; no other profiles shown)

I know that the option was there a few months ago, but I'm not sure how or why it was disabled, or how to reinstate it. What I *am* able to see or use are:

- A faint "switch user" button on the lock screen
- A "switch user" option when pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>.
- The `tsdiscon.exe` command.

When I use any of those options I am taken to the login screen *where I am prompted for **my own** password again*; I can choose sign-in method (password/PIN/biometric) but there is no option to actually log on as anyone else without rebooting the computer.

#### Similar problems reported

- [Q&A on *answers.microsoft.com* in 2015](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/how-do-i-re-enable-fast-user-switching-in-windows/9a08745c-adf4-41af-893f-39dfc4aad3e4)

#### Version(s) affected

- Windows 10 Pro version 1909, build 18363.836
- Probably earlier versions, but I didn't make notes before the 1909 update

#### Workaround

I have found a workaround using `secpol.msc`: I **Enabled** the following policy:

```
Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options
Interactive Logon: Don't display last signed-in
```

I believe this is the same as setting the following DWORD value in the registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"dontdisplaylastusername" = 1
```

Now I can enter the username & password for other users from the logon screen, and switch between them, but I'd like to be able to switch between them more smoothly (i.e. profile picture + password).

*How do I reinstate the expected "entry points" to switch users/logon with a profile picture?*

### Solutions attempted

#### Change (Group) Policy settings

Using the **Local Group Policy Editor** I have made sure that the **Hide entry points for Fast User Switching** policy is **Not Configured** in:

```
Local Computer Policy:
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Logon
```

I have tried setting this to **Disabled** but that made no difference.

I have checked with `gpresult /r` that there are no Group Policies in place for this laptop (a "standalone" workstation).

#### Change Registry Settings

Many sites mention the following registry key/value, however this does not exist:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"HideFastUserSwitching"
```

I have tried creating this value and setting it to 0 (disabled) but that made no difference.

Further searching for `HideFastUserSwitching` only finds the following:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\WindowsLogon\HideFastUserSwitching]
"Behavior"=dword:00002021
"highrange"=dword:00000001
"lowrange"=dword:00000000
"mergealgorithm"=dword:00000002
"policytype"=dword:00000004
"RegKeyPathRedirect"="Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System"
"RegValueNameRedirect"="HideFastUserSwitching"
"value"=dword:00000000
```

This appears to be a reference to the Group Policy setting mentioned above.

> Added in Windows 10, version 1703. This policy setting allows you to hide the Switch account button on the sign-in screen, Start, and the Task Manager. If you enable this policy setting, the Switch account button is hidden from the user who is attempting to sign-in or is signed in to the computer that has this policy applied. If you disable or do not configure this policy setting, the Switch account button is accessible to the user in the three locations.
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-windowslogon#windowslogon-hidefastuserswitching

**NOTE**: The Policy configuration service provider enables the enterprise to configure policies on Windows 10. Use this configuration service provider to configure any company policies.

Answer (score 1):

I had precisely the same problem on 21H2 LTSC.
"Interactive Logon: Don't display last signed-in" is a reasonable short-term solution.
I solved the problem by an in-place upgrade from 21H2 to 22H2, which aligns with the solution from the topic starter.

Comment: It seems reasonable to suggest an upgrade to the latest patch/version of Windows to fix this problem, but it doesn't really feel like the answer. However this may be the best we can do.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours researching this and typing up the question above, it seems that running the v2004 update for Windows 10 has fixed the problem.

I have verified this by reversing the "workaround" mentioned above and I now have a list of profiles offered to me in the login screen. I'm not sure why the update fixed the problem, what caused it in the first place or why the attempted fixes didn't work.

One thing I noticed after the 2004 update was that, in the **Family & other users** settings, my own MS account was shown as "Can't sign in". I toggled that on/off before thinking to check whether the 2004 update had fixed my original problem.

Another thing that has nagged at me is whether the problem started/was caused by someone else clicking the **Add a work or school account** option for their profile.

Comment: Please remove the question from your answer and ask a new question instead.

Comment: It wasn't meant to a question one looking for an answer in this thread... I'll ask a new question if needs be, but I don't think I can make it a "good" one (minimal, verifiable, etc.)